# bipartite graph with vertex partition?

Tags: integer-partitions, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with vertex partition $V(G) = V_1 \cup V_2$ such that $|V_1|= a$ and $|V_2| = a + 2$. Show that: $|E(G)| \leq a^2 + 2a$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question or how to begin

Comment: Start by understanding what it means to have a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). What they are asking is for you to prove that the graph as no more than $a^2 + 2a$ edges.

Comment: since each element in v1 can be connected with the elements of v2 in (a+2) ways. since v1 has 'a' elements and each element of v1 can be connected with the elements of v2 in maximum of (a+2) ways. so the total number of maximum ways is a(a+2) = a^2+2a ways. by treating each way as an edge, the maximum number of edges that can be drawn from vertext set v1 to a vertex set v2 is a^2+2a. Hence |E(G)| <= a^2 + 2a.

Comment: I just need help writing this out in notation, i understand the concept but I need to write it out using the notation

Comment: that is absolutely correct. That was fine. Do you need me to write it out with the notation?

Comment: if you can please, that is the only thing i struggle a lot with that i need to practice more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say that $G$ is a bipartite graph with partitions $V_1$ and $V_2$, such that $|V_1| = a$ and $|V_2| = a + 2$. Because the graph is bipartite, we know that every edge connects one vertex from $V_1$ to a vertex from $V_2$. For each vertex in $V_1$, it can be connected to, at most, $a + 2$ vertices since that is the number of vertices in $V_2$. Given that there are $a$ vertices in $V_1$, we can have a maximum of $a(a + 2) = a^2 + 2a$ edges in the whole graph.